# Cross check email addresses and delete the entire row of duplicates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to merge 2 files into 1 and would like to crosscheck the email addresses to find duplicates and delete the entire row that it's contained in. Is this possible?

So far I just copy pasted all the data in one single sheet but each on a new page/worksheet but can't seem to find anything to do what I need. Any advice? Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: which version of ms office?

Comment: 2010, sorry for not mentioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Excel 2007 or 2010:

Select your data. Go to the Data tab -> Remove duplicates. Uncheck every column except the one that contains your emails, and press OK.

Comment: Woot worked, thank you :] Well kinda. It deletes all the duplicate email addresses but not the entire row, and since it reorders the email addresses by default then it assigns the email address to the wrong rows which should have been deleted, any idea?

Comment: @HateNames Did you select all your data, or just the column with email addresses?

Comment: Ah I see...that did it, sorry for messing up when you gave me the correct answer from the beginning. Many thanks.

Comment: @HateNames No problem, glad it worked for you.